# Font for text inside SVG in jetpack compose

Tags: android, svg, fonts, jetpack, coil

I want to show svg from remote server. It has text tags in it. When I load the svg into app its font differs.

I tried changed url of font that loads from app’s res folder. Make it load from another website.
In web browser font is OK.

Is there any method to pass custom font into coil svg loader in order to render the text with that font.